# How to download json code with the help of query in rdf database?

Tags: database, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, stardog

I have a RDF database in my stardog server locally and in which I have one graph now I want to download data of selected  stardog:044585392... in JSON or any type of file like RDF/XML with the help of the query see the image for more detail so how do i do it?  [image]

Comment: just use a `DESCRIBE` query for that URI: `DESCRIBE <URI_HERE>`

Comment: Hi there i see thanks now if i want to download/get data in json format how do i do that?

Comment: You can use the "Run to File" button and select JSON to download a file from Studio

Comment: @BryanA that's manual I want something in query itself

Comment: I don't think there is anything in SPARQL to do that.  Can you use a `curl` or something like Python?  The HTTP API will return the results in XML by default and you can specify JSON for the response.  That way you keep it programatic.  https://stardog-union.github.io/http-docs/#operation/get